# Replace numbers in list with strings from another list in Python

Tags: python, list, replace

I have a list of numbers and list of strings:

```
data = [1, 2, 3, 1, 3]
labels = ['a','b','c']
```

How do I replace the numbers in data with the labels so that I will get data equals:

```
['a','b','c','a','c']
```

I tried setting labels to

```
mappings [('a', 1), ('b',2), ('c',3)]
```

and using a for loop to replace the data variable but I cannot seem to replace a list.

Comment: something like `[labels[i-1] for i in data]` should work

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Replace values in array of indexes corresponding to another array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54594554/replace-values-in-array-of-indexes-corresponding-to-another-array)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

simple list comprehension with offset correction (in that case you don't need a dictionary)

```
data = [1, 2, 3, 1, 3]
labels = ['a','b','c']    

>>> [labels[i-1] for i in data]
['a', 'b', 'c', 'a', 'c']
```

with a dictionary:

```
mappings = {1: 'a', 2: 'b', 3: 'c'}
>>> [mappings[i] for i in data]
['a', 'b', 'c', 'a', 'c']
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use numpy for this:

```
import numpy as np
import itertools
np.array(labels)[[a - b for a,b in zip(data, itertools.cycle([1]))]].tolist() 

#  ['a', 'b', 'c', 'a', 'c']
```